# Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process nodejs and shared hosting

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, sequelize.js

I am experiencing problem with node js, sequelize and shared hosting. My code perfectly working on localhost. But when i upload it on the server i am experiencing this king of error.

```
App 3626586 output:     at InstanceValidator._validate (/home/mu1ivodr6k5d/nodevenv/p_player/10/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:78:13)
[ N 2021-07-15 10:12:10.6452 1086384/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1147 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 3626078, application /home/mu1ivodr6k5d/p_player (production)
```

Can't understand where i have made mistakes. i need some guide.

Comment: anyone here to help me, i am struggling with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a better question to ask on the hosting platform.. But a lot of times shared node hosting will have different node versions, I would check to ensure both local and hosting node versions are the same first.

Ultimately though, if its working locally but not on the server its probably due to a config mismatch only they would be able to answer